# Sub Account creation in sub Account

Tags: node.js, express

I want to invite members to join team through email where a team members can perform specific task like in sendgrid. I am using node and express.So, Please provide me logic for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use express-session to identify user sessions and store informations in a database. Make a login system, then allow them to invite people in their team by giving them specific rights. Don't forget to write middlewares that will check user rights before performing actions.

Your question is not specific enough by the way